# Post Journal Entries to EPICOR 905 using C#

Tags: c#, epicorerp, epicor

I'm trying to connect to Epicor905 and post a journal entry programmatically. 
I found the below code which connects to Epicor. However, I am unable to locate any info on accessing the GL Journal Entry module. I'm fairly new to C# and just want someone to point me in the right direction logically/technically. I understand that the core of it is working with DLLs and the business objects. But beyond that I am clueless. Here is the code I found to connect to EPICOR:

```
using Ice.Core;
using Erp.Common;

 try
            {
            Session obj = new Session("manager", "manager", Session.LicenseType.Default, @"C:\Epicor\E10Pilot.sysconfig");

            if (obj != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sesion valida");
                obj.Dispose();                    
                obj = null;                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Word on the street is that you should have a login/pass for this site: https://epicweb.epicor.com/ which should contain the documentation you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to identify the calls required is to start client tracing and run through the process you wish to automate in the UI. This will record the calls that the UI makes for your particular process. You should then be able to replicate them in your code.

You will need to reference the contract assembly for each BO required from your client directory.

This will take some experimentation to identify the right calls but this is exactly how the CSG team in Epicor would approach this.